# Flutter: Same Firestore timestamp and calendar timestamp shows different results

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I'm using Firestore to display events in [Table Calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar). On date press I pass selected date as `DateTime` to new page:

```
void _onDaySelected(DateTime selectedDay, DateTime focusedDay) {
    if (!isSameDay(_selectedDay, selectedDay)) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedDay = selectedDay;
        _focusedDay = focusedDay;
      });
    }
    _selectedEvents.value = _getEventsForDay(selectedDay);

    if (_selectedEvents.value.isEmpty)
      _showSnackbar(context, 'No events for that day');
    else {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return EventDialogBox(
            text: _selectedEvents.value.toString(),
            date: _selectedDay!,
            data: eventList,
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

In new page I convert it to Timestamp `Timestamp dateCompare = Timestamp.fromDate(widget.date);` In this page I want to display data from Firestore in `StreamBuilder` like this: `final Stream<QuerySnapshot> selectedEvents = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('events').where('date', isEqualTo: widget.date).snapshots();` But I'm not getting any data.

After I used print and got this:

```
I/flutter ( 4023): DateCompare: Timestamp(seconds=1629331200, nanoseconds=0)
I/flutter ( 4023): Timezone name: +06
I/flutter ( 4023): Timezone offset: 6:00:00.000000
I/flutter ( 4023): From Firestore: Timestamp(seconds=1629309600, nanoseconds=0)
I/flutter ( 4023): Firestore Timezone name: +06
I/flutter ( 4023): Firestore Timezone offset: 6:00:00.000000
```

Based on logs i don't know what is the problem. I successfully loaded stream by creating new Timestamp `Timestamp testTime = new Timestamp(dateCompare.seconds - 21600, 0);` In it i subtracted 6 hours and it worked. Is there any ways to convert device time to UTC +6 time, so i can load data from Firestore in any device?

Comment: There's not enough information here.  We need to be able to see all the code for a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that anyone can copy and run that duplicates the behavior that doesn't work the way you expect, including the contents of the database.

Comment: @DougStevenson Well, i added a lot of details. Any ideas why i'm having this problem?

Comment: As you are not getting any data after adding the filtering criteria there might be no data in your Firestore Database which meet your filtering condition. I would suggest you remove the filter and retrieve the data to verify the value you are using for filtering is correct.